# a2ensite from script path

Tags: apache, vhosts

I'm trying to automate some new site deployment in my testing environment. My script auto generates the apache vhost file in

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/testsite.com
```

then a2ensite is run via the same script

```
a2ensite /etc/apache2/sites-available/testsite.com
```

I get:

```
ERROR: No site found matching /etc/apache2/sites-available/testsite.com!
```

The script is being run as root.

I read that you must a2ensite from the sites-available directory but if this is being done via script how would I tell a2ensite to think its in the proper directory?

Thanks,

Comment: @raina77ow that was it. sometimes the answer is too simple :D thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

a2ensite's [man page](http://man.he.net/man8/a2ensite) doesn't mention it explicitly, but you actually should supply just a name of the site to be enabled, like...

```
a2ensite testsite.com
```

... and not the whole path to it.

Comment: This is not working for me same problem. Everything seems fine same error.

Comment: `a2ensite testsite.com.conf` <-- actually it's a **file name** that is required. This could be the same as the site name, but I usually see a `.conf` extension on it. This file resides in the sites-available directory. You're right, the a2ensite man-page drops the ball on this.